# Visual studio 2013 - WSDL code gen using different runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wsdl, visual-studio-2013, web-reference

I have upgraded a VS 2008 solution to VS 2013.

It has a `reference.cs` is built from a **WSDL** using `Runtime Version:2.0.50727.4455` (in vs 2008)

When it is built using VS 2013 it uses `Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18408` which makes the auto-gen class inherit from a different base class causing errors due to a missing property.

Is it possible to change this run time the auto-generated code uses in VS 2013?

Comment: I bet that if you delete the reference in your project and then re-add it in the ide then the compiler will be happy:)